# Trigger that delete row if currentdatetime > datetime+5

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm creating a database where i want to create a trigger.

This trigger will delete a row if the current time is 5 min over the requesttime in the table.

The requesttime is a datetime attribute in the table.

How can i make a trigger which do this?

Comment: First understand what a trigger is and when is it fired. Read some notes at [*Wiki: Database trigger*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do this.  First, triggers only run when something is happening inside the database (such as an insert or update).  They are not the same as scheduled jobs.  Second, you generally don't want to do this in a scheduled job.  Instead, just create a view:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*
    from table t
    where requesttime >= now() - interval 5 minute;
```

This will return valid requests.

Then, at your leisure, delete the old rows -- if you really need to.  There is a good chance you might want to keep them around to know what happened in the past.  But you can delete them on Sunday morning at 3:00 a.m. or some other slow time, if you want.

Comment: Okay so an better approach would be in my php script to check wether now() >= requesttime+5 ?

Comment: @user3423384 . . . No.  A better approach is to add a `where` clause in the SQL statement or just use a view that gets things requested in the last five minutes.

Comment: This view delete all the content. What i need is a view that only delete the rows where requesttime >= now() - interval 5 minute.

Comment: @user3423384 . . . The view doesn't "delete" anything.  It only returns the rows that appeared in the last five minutes.  If you want older rows, then reverse the `>=` to `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) added in MySQL 5.1.6. Events can be seen as an alternative to Cronjob.

Their main advantages are:

1. Platform independent; directly written in MySsql
2. Ability to list all events `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS;`
3. Built in error logging option

Syntax is something similar to:

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 MINUTE
    STARTS '2015-01-01 00:15:00'
COMMENT 'Removes forgotten password tokens older thank 1 week.'    
DO
    DELETE FROM my_table WHERE some_timestamp > NOW();
```